# Go Interfaces with more than one method - Acceptable or unacceptable?

Tags: go, idioms

Is there anything wrong with an interface with more that one function assigned to it ?

Everywhere I read, an interface should ideally have only one method (which is what the interface should be named after). But are there any pit falls to having more than one method for an interface ?
Ex.

```
type FooMgrInterface interface {
    CreateFoo(hostname string, fooConfig interface{}) (uuid string, err error)
    DeleteFoo(hostname string, fooID string) (err error)
    CreateBar(hostname string, barID string, barConfig interface{}) (uuid string, err error)
    DeleteBar(hostname string, barID string) (err error)
    AttachBar(hostname string, fooID string, bars []string) (err error)
    DetachBar(hostname string, barID string) (err error)
    GetBars(hostname string) (bars []Bar, err error)
    GetBar(hostname string, barID string) (bar Bar, err error)
    GetFoo(hostname string, fooID string) (foo Foo, err error)
    GetFoos(hostname string) (foos []Foo, err error)
}
```

If so how could the above interface be simplified or (maybe) split into multiple interfaces ?

Comment: It's okay, but 10 methods just seems wrong. The standard library itself has cases of 2-3 methods (sync.Locker, sort.Interface) that are not composed, and I do that in my code as well some time. but in your case it seems like something is off in the way you're thinking of interfaces.

Comment: Your code looks remarkably similar to [this example](https://youtu.be/ltqV6pDKZD8?t=29m13s)… Watch about 3 minutes of it to understand why it's considered an anti-pattern. That doesn't mean it's wrong. It's just a lot of methods required for a type to implement a single interface, which might beg questions like: Is this an interface just to have an interface to pass around to avoid relying on concrete types? Do all the methods of this interface really need to be in this interface?

Comment: @ChronoKitsune its more from the aspect of interchangeability. Its more on the lines of implementing the proxy pattern. My applications to know only about the methods mentioned above in the interface. These methods should never change. What changes is how they are implemented (think 3rd party libraries).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for inspiration in https://golang.org/src/io/io.go

You will see:

a. "Atomic" interfaces: `Reader`, `Writer`, `Closer`, `Seeker`

b. Composed interfaces: `ReaderWriter`, `ReaderWriterSeeker`, `ReaderSeekerCloser` etc.

Golang will not complaint about gigantic interfaces, it's you and your collegues will have complaints about big monolithic interfaces.

I recomend  divide your interface to 4 (maybe 2) interfaces: `FooOps`, `FoosOps`, `BarOps`, `BarsOps` and then define composed interfaces from them.

Comment: You're right. I am considering breaking it into two interface and one composed interface for them. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing wrong with it, in that the language supports it just fine.

I believe the authors are offering architectural advice based on experience.  Specifically, if your interface has many methods, you likely have the wrong abstraction somewhere.

You can ask yourself some clarifying questions:

- How many different implementations of this interface will there be?
- How many of them will have identical method implementations?
- How are the Foos/Bars attached to the implementor?  Would it be simpler to reverse it somehow? eg something like `NewFoo(owner FooMgrInterface) *Foo`